# Is it possible to stop a loop with another function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is continuously incrementing a value.  I am trying to implement a reset button that would reset the value to 0 and prevent it from incrementing any more.  However, the reset button only changes the value but the loop keeps on going.  Here is the code that accomplishes that (the actual value that is increasing is not mentioned in this block, the counter variable is involved with the rate at which the value is increased):

```
var counter = 0;

function create() {
//creates stuff
}

var timer;


function loop() {
        create()
}

function counter() {
    clearInterval(timer)
    timer = setInterval(loop, 1000 / (2**counter))
}
```

And it works as expected.  However, my reset button looks like this:

```
function reset() {
    counter = 0
    clearInterval(timer)
    timer = setInterval(loop, 0)
```

The counter just continues to increase at the same rate it was before the reset.  Is it possible to terminate this process?

Comment: `setInterval(loop, 0)` doesn't make sense

Comment: well in the case of the code you provided, nothing is being changed that affects the loop interval.

Comment: Am I right if I assume counter is incremented at every loop? In that case, is there any particular reason for setting an interval rather than a timeout?

Comment: there is a function and a variable both are named `counter`

Comment: @emperorcrimson ... also what exactly gets incremented?.. `counter` (the `var`iable) always remains `0` and thus a new interval constantly would be initialized with 1000msec. What does the op really want to achieve?

Comment: clearInterval() may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try below?

```js
function initCounter() { 
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(loop, 1000 / (2**counter));
} 

function reset() { 
  counter = 0;
  initCounter(); 
}
```